# set default of selected modes to nothing (no content)>

Tags: xslt

Ok when we often use this trick:

```
<xsl:template match="...." mode="m1">my custom output</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*" mode="m1"/>
```

it slowly becomes annoying to always have to do this:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="m1"/>
<xsl:template match="*" mode="m2"/>
<xsl:template match="*" mode="m3"/>
<xsl:template match="*" mode="m4"/>..
```

And if we do not do it it will give us the "default" template which basically outputs the text content for a text node.. eeks!

Is there a shortcut to the code above?:

Im thinking:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="m1|m2|m3|m4"/>
```

Well of course it doesn't work but you get my idea..

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a shortcut to the code
>   above?:
>
> Im thinking:
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="*" mode="m1|m2|m3|m4"/>
> ```
>
> Well of course it doesn't work but you
>   get my idea..

Yes. In XSLT 2.0 one can have:

```
 <xsl:template match="*" mode="m1 m2 m3"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT 2.0 you can use `<xsl:template match="*" mode="#all">...</xsl:template>`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#modes.

Comment: Martin, the OP asks for a way to provide a specific set of modes, not all modes.

Answer (score 0):

not as far as i know, using the mode suggests its explicit template you wish to call